# Obter valor de varias Entry Python

Tags: python, tkinter

A ideia é que o usuário digite o numero de linhas e eu crie as entry de acordo com essa quantidade, isso eu consegui fazer, o que não estou conseguindo é obter o valor dessas entry com get().

```
        y1=0
        lista= []
        while y1 < x1:
            y1= y1+1             

            lista.append(y1)              


            for y1 in lista:
                self.num= Label(self.root, text= y1,font= fonte, bg=cor).grid(row=(9+y1), column=0,sticky= NW)
                self.cxx = Entry(self.root)
                self.cxx["width"] = 4
                self.cxx["font"] = fonte
                self.cxx.grid(row=(9+y1), column=1)
```

Comment: Sugiro que crie um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema, para que seja fácil de o reproduzir e testar. Ainda assim não vejo nenhum `get` no código que tem na pergunta. Já para não falar que todas as `Entry` estão a ser guardados umas por cima das outras

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você tem que criar várias `StringVar`, uma pra cada entry:

```
self.entry_vars = [] # lista com todas as StringVars
for y1 in lista:
    sv = StringVar()           # cria uma StringVar e armazena
    self.entry_vars.append(sv) # na lista para uso posterior
    cx = Entry(self.root, textvariable=sv)
    cx["width"] = 4
    cx["font"] = fonte
    cx.grid(row=(9+y1), column=1)
```

Depois é só usar essa lista de `StringVar`s para pegar o texto de cada entry:

```
x = self.entry_vars[2].get() # valor da terceira entry
```

Se tudo o que você quer é pegar o valor das `Entry`s, você nem precisa armazenar uma referência ao entry, somente os `StringVar` são suficientes para pegar os valores depois.